# GAS - Dropdown List In Google Form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I'm trying to add items into my 'ListItem' from spreadsheet to be displayed whenever user enters google form.

Copied this from google developer reference,

```
var form = FormApp.openById('1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
var item = form.addListItem();
item.setTitle('Do you prefer cats or dogs?');
item.setChoiceValues(['Dogs', 'Cats']);
```

How do I loop it properly to add in all the items? My current code below is flawed.

```
var items = form.getItems();
var item = items[1];
var itemList = item.asListItem();
var SS = SpreadsheetApp.openById("123456").getSheetByName('List').getDataRange().getValues();
for (var i = 1; i < SS.length; i++){
    var row = teacherSS[i];
    itemList.setChoices([row[i]]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For adding the values to the listItem, you can do it this way

```
function testAdding(){
var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
var item = form.addListItem();
item.setTitle('Do you prefer cats or dogs?');

var SS = SpreadsheetApp.openById("123456").getSheetByName('List').getDataRange().getValues();
item.setChoiceValues(SS);

}
```

If you want to add the listItem on form open, you can try using [triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/).

Hope that helps!